# Loop without Loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA. Below is code that applies a validation list to cells in column `C` depending on what option from another validation list was selected in column `B`. It's clunky and slow. I was hoping for some ideas on a different way to write it. Here's what I have:

```
For k = 36 To 88

    If Range("B" & k) Is Nothing Then
    Else
        CarrierName = Range("B" & k)
        Range("C" & k).Name = "PlanName"
        xPlanDropDown = PlanDropDown(CarrierName, PlanName)
    End If

    Next k

End Sub

Function PlanDropDown(CarrierName, PlanName)

    Select Case CarrierName

        Case "Aetna EPO"
              Range("PlanName").Validation _
                .Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Plans!A2:A101"
        Case "Aetna HMO"
              Range("PlanName").Validation _
                .Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Plans!B2:B101"
        Case "Aetna PPO"
              Range("PlanName").Validation _
                .Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Plans!C2:C101"  ...
```

Thank you for any help you can provide! Cheryl

Comment: I think that the best way to speed up VBA is ... to not use VBA :] http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to VBA!

Not so much an answer but this should speed up your VBA considerably.  This would go into the **FIRST** subroutine that calls any and all other VBA routines.  You wouldn't for example, place it into the **FUNCTION** you referenced.

Add this to the top of your **SUB**:

```
Dim PrevCalc As XlCalculation
With Application
    PrevCalc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .Cursor = xlWait
    .Calculate
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    '.ScreenUpdating = False ' Not really needed
End With
```

then add this to the bottom:

```
With Application
    .Cursor = xlDefault
    .Calculate
    .Calculation = PrevCalc
    '.ScreenUpdating = True 'Not really needed
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```